# Aggregating Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle11g, timestamp, case, aggregate-functions

I'm working with the following query:

```
    SELECT contract,
     source_ref1 AS "ORDER_NO",
     part_no,
     ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_description( contract, part_no ) as "DESCRIPTION",
     ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_unit_meas( contract, part_no ) as "UNIT_MEAS",
     date_applied,
     (SELECT work_center_no FROM shop_order_operation where inventory_transaction_hist2.source_ref1 = shop_order_operation.order_no) AS "WORK_CENTER",
    direction,
       SUM( quantity ) AS "QUANTITY",
       ( CASE
           WHEN ( ( To_char( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI ' ) BETWEEN '05:45 ' AND '17:44' ) AND
                  date_applied = date_created ) THEN 'SHIFT1'
           WHEN (( ( To_char( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI' ) BETWEEN '17:45' AND '24:00' )  OR
                   ( To_char( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI' ) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:44' ) AND
                   date_applied = date_created )) THEN 'SHIFT2'
           ELSE 'MANUAL_ADJUST'
         END ) AS "SHIFT"
FROM   ifsapp.INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST2
WHERE  part_no IN (select pc.part_no from ifsapp.HH_INV_PART_CHARS pc where pc.accounting_group = '400') AND
       contract IN ( 'DE1', 'DE2' ) AND
       transaction_code LIKE '%REC%' AND
       direction IN ( '+', '-' ) AND
       source_ref_type = 'Shop Order' AND
       To_char( date_applied, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-26'
GROUP BY contract,source_ref1, part_no, ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_description( contract, part_no ), 
ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_unit_meas( contract, part_no ), location_no, date_applied, direction,
date_time_created, date_created
ORDER  BY date_applied
```

This query returns 18292 hits.

If I remove the CASE statement, and remove DATE_TIME_CREATED and DATE_CREATED from the GROUP BY section, then the query will return 1356 hits.

We're using the CASE statement to determine what shift our product was produced. The date_time_created field is basically a time stamp. It's the only field on that table that we can use to determine what shift the product was produced.

But, it's also resulting in us getting 10X as many hits as we would without it.

Take ORDER_NO 349321 as example. Running the query as shown, I get 61 hits. Removing the CASE statement,  and remove DATE_TIME_CREATED and DATE_CREATED from the GROUP BY section, I get two hits.

We don't have orders completed over two shifts. So, I don't need to know the time stamp for every transaction for ORDER_NO 349321, and I don't need to know whether every time stamp is in Shift 1 or Shift 2. I just need to know if transactions for that order were completed in Shift 1 or Shift 2.

Is there any way to aggregate the information that I'm getting from that case statement to work this out? I've tried using MAX and AVG in my case statement but it's returning the same number of results.

Comment: Provide representative data sample and the desired result.

Comment: Unless you did it intentionally, it looks like you're missing a set of parentheses around the OR condition in your "SHIFT 2" calculation.  The way it is now, the "AND" conditions are not being treated as "ANDs" since the OR is not linked to any other condition.

`(
 (
  ( TO_CHAR( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI' ) BETWEEN '17:45' AND '24:00' )  OR
  ( TO_CHAR( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI' ) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:44' ) AND
 date_applied = date_created 
 )
)` 

This doesn't fix your original issue, but something to note for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to project the DATE_TIME_CREATED and DATE_CREATED columns, try doing the "SHIFT" calculation in a sub-query before you do your aggregate processing.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    contract,
    source_ref1 AS "ORDER_NO",
    part_no,
    ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_description( contract, part_no ) AS "DESCRIPTION",
    ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_unit_meas( contract, part_no ) AS "UNIT_MEAS",
    date_applied,
    (SELECT work_center_no FROM shop_order_operation WHERE inventory_transaction_hist2.source_ref1 = shop_order_operation.order_no) AS "WORK_CENTER",
    direction,
    SUM(quantity) AS "QUANTITY",
    "SHIFT"
FROM 
(
    SELECT contract, source_ref1, part_no, date_applied, direction, quantity, 
    ( CASE
       WHEN ( ( TO_CHAR( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI ' ) BETWEEN '05:45 ' AND '17:44' ) AND
              date_applied = date_created ) THEN 'SHIFT1'
       WHEN (( ( TO_CHAR( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI' ) BETWEEN '17:45' AND '24:00' )  OR
               ( TO_CHAR( date_time_created, 'HH24:MI' ) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:44' ) AND
               date_applied = date_created )) THEN 'SHIFT2'
       ELSE 'MANUAL_ADJUST'
     END ) AS "SHIFT"
    FROM ifsapp.INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST2
    WHERE part_no IN (SELECT pc.part_no FROM ifsapp.HH_INV_PART_CHARS pc WHERE pc.accounting_group = '400') 
    AND contract IN ( 'DE1', 'DE2')
    AND transaction_code LIKE '%REC%' 
    AND direction IN ( '+', '-') 
    AND source_ref_type = 'Shop Order' 
    AND TO_CHAR( date_applied, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-26'
) src
GROUP BY 
    contract,
    source_ref1, 
    part_no, 
    ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_description(contract, part_no), 
    ifsapp.inventory_part_api.Get_unit_meas(contract, part_no), 
    location_no, 
    date_applied, 
    direction
--  ,date_time_created, 
--  date_created
ORDER  BY date_applied
```

I don't have any DDL/data to test the query, so you'll definitely get some syntax errors.  But give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Also, check your "SHIFT" calculation, it looks like you have a floating "OR" in there without parentheses.

Comment: You got it my friend :)